# windows recovery vs Dell backup

Tags: windows-8

I got Dell Inspiron 15Z with Windows 8 last week.
It has no DVD for Windows Re-installation.

Suppose at any time, my OS crashes & I need to re-install,would it be a better option to do that via Windows Recovery(the one in control panel) or using the Dell Backup & Recovery ?
ie,Which one would be a cleaner install ?

Also,I dont have my product key(& I dont want to use any external softwares to read it out for me from BIOS)

Lastly, in control Panel, there's this windows 7 file recovery too, is that for OS-reinstallation too ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well ...

- **Dell Backup & Recovery** will make an image of the **Recovery Partition** (It's hidden on your HHD)

  It will back your laptop to **the condition you bought it with** (Removing the partitions you created and the Apps)

**So you should make a backup of your files on External Hard Disc.**

- **Windows Recovery**(the one in control panel) .. It will **do the same**.

**But None of them is a Clean install....**

- To do a **Clean install** you have to obtain **a Windows 8 installation Media DVD** Or **an 
  image** to **burn it to DVD or USB stick**.
- To get your **Product key** .. You have to use **a Third party Software** (small tools)
- **Windows 7 File Recovery** is to **backup your files**.

  **Hope it helps**

Comment: **You use** bold a lot **in** this **question**.

Comment: Thank you.
However, in Dell Backup & Recovery, I can see an option to "reinstall disks", which is different from "backup your data" option. Moreover, this reinstall disk option requires a USB or DVDs so its fair to assume it's talking about only OS & not entire data on Laptop(my mistake that I didnt mention this in my question).But my question seems almost answered by you, ie Dell is better because other options dont provide only-OS backup.I was under the impression that Windows Recovery can also do only-OS backup.Thanks for clearing it up.

Answer (score 0):

If your OS crashes how are you going to get into the control panel? If you have a recovery partition boot off of that. If you don't have a product key stuck to the side of your case you will have to extract with third party tools.

Comment: I mean to ask that which recovery/backup option I should use today, that would prove to be more useful than other, in case my OS crashes anytime in future.

Comment: Windows 8 ships with the key in the bios. Windows setup only asks for a key if it can't find that key on its own. No need to extract out

Answer (score 0):

Dell's tool is better because it is always available, even if windows is dead. But you should get recovery media because the hard drive may go corrupt.

Comment: I'm least bothered about any data on hard drive getting lost.Just want to get the OS-backup into disc/usb.